# How to read React.Children.map api notation?

Tags: reactjs

Looking at the [code for React.Children.map](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactChildren.js#L339), it looks like the function takes up to 3 args.

The api doc for [React.Children.map](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap) shows

`React.Children.map(children, function[(thisArg)])`

If it can take 3 args I expected to see 2 commas in there somewhere.

### My question is

How do you read `React.Children.map(children, function[(thisArg)])` in plain english?

So far I have "React.Children.map is a function that..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function[(thisArg)]` isn't a standard denotation. As [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap) states, `map`

> Invokes a function on every immediate child contained within children with this set to thisArg.

`Children.map` signature is similar to JavaScript [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). There are 3 arguments, 3rd argument is optional `this` context for callback function if needed.

`Children.map` is documented better in [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.6.1/packages/react/src/ReactChildren.js):

```
/**
 * Maps children that are typically specified as `props.children`.
 *
 * See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap
 *
 * The provided mapFunction(child, key, index) will be called for each
 * leaf child.
 *
 * @param {?*} children Children tree container.
 * @param {function(*, int)} func The map function.
 * @param {*} context Context for mapFunction.
 * @return {object} Object containing the ordered map of results.
 */
function mapChildren(children, func, context) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond but this doesn't answer my question. Your answer restates things that I already know from reading the docs and looking at the code. I'm not asking how to use React.Children.map but rather, I want to know how the api notation tells me how to use React.Children.map. Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned, that this isn't standard notation. The answer explains what it really stands for. You can read it as *React.Children.map is a function that accepts children argument, callback function argument and optional thisArg argument that will be used as `this` context in callback function*. Can anyone read it like that without knowing what it stands for? I doubt that.